# Calculate makefile build time

Tags: build, makefile, environment-variables

Any creative idea how to use enviroment variables to calculate full build time of a makefile? Can I store the time somewhere and compare it in the end?

Comment: It would depend what operating system you are talking about. And
suppose it could be done *without* environment variables?

Comment: mingw make version 3.82, WIN7 OS. it could be done either way, with or without e-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 7 you've got PowerShell. So we'll assume:

- Your makefile `Makefile` is in directory `C:\Dev\ProjDir`
- Your make tool is `mingw32-make` and is in your `PATH`

If PowerShell isn't your usual console then do:

```
C:\Dev\ProjDir>powershell
```

At the PowerShell prompt, run:

```
PS C:\Dev\ProjDir> Measure-Command { mingw32-make | Out-Default }
```

This will run your build and display the output, followed by
a timing report, e.g.

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 244
Ticks             : 2443841
TotalDays         : 2.82851967592593E-06
TotalHours        : 6.78844722222222E-05
TotalMinutes      : 0.00407306833333333
TotalSeconds      : 0.2443841
TotalMilliseconds : 244.3841
```

**Continued for OP's follow-up:**

> I was wondering if it is possible to be implemented as part of the makefile, 
>   so I can decide which part to measure

The idea of timing "part of a makefile" does not make clear sense. When you run `make`, it parses
the entire makefile *before* it makes anything and works out the entire sequence of
steps it must take to make the specified or default target(s). Then, it takes all those
steps.

Perhaps you want to measure the time taken to make a particular set of targets? You
can do that in the way already described. For example, suppose that your makefile
can make two libraries `libfoo.lib` and `libbar.lib` and you would like to time the
build of just `libfoo.lib`. To make `libfoo.lib` by itself, the make command you would
run is:

```
mingw32-make libfoo.lib
```

So to time this command, run:

```
PS C:\Dev\ProjDir> Measure-Command { mingw32-make libfoo.lib | Out-Default }
```

Or suppose that your makefile makes `app.exe` from source files `foo.c` and `bar.c`, and
you would like to time just the build of the object files `foo.obj`, `bar.obj`. The
make command you would run to build just those object files is:

```
mingw32-make foo.obj bar.obj
```

So you would time it with:

```
PS C:\Dev\ProjDir> Measure-Command { mingw32-make foo.obj bar.obj | Out-Default }
```

Perhaps you would like to be able to invoke powershell's `Measure-Command` inside your makefile
to time the building of particular targets?

For this, you need a command that invokes PowerShell to run some other command. That is:

```
powershell -c "some other command"
```

So in your makefile you can add a target for timing the build of any other targets:

```
.phony: time
time:
    powershell -c "Measure-Command { $(MAKE) $(targets) | Out-Default }"
```

You would use the `time` target like so:

```
C:\Dev\ProjDir>mingw32-make time targets=app.exe
```

or:

```
C:\Dev\ProjDir>mingw32-make time targets="foo.obj bar.obj"
```

And of course, in your makefile, the commands to build a particular target can
include `powershell -c "some other command"` wherever you like.

Comment: This indeed working, but I was wondering if it is possible to be implemented as part of the makefile, so I can decide which part to measure

Comment: Allright the "-c" option solves my problem, i can just point out eclipse build with the PowerShell -c "...." Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. If you think an answer solves your problem, it is appropriate to *accept* it: [see how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 6):

I know the OP meant Windows OS, but for the record, on any Linux machine you can use `time`:

```
>time make -j
real     0m9.774s
user     0m31.562s
sys      0m1.092s
```